# How to exclude Data Type Descriptors returned from a DynamoDB QueryRequest?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, dynamodb-queries

I'm learning DynamoDB and am trying to run a query using the .NET SDK for AWS.  I set up a `QueryRequest` with a `KeyConditionExpression` defined so I can search on a partition key.

```
        var request = new QueryRequest
        {
            TableName = "MyTable",
            KeyConditionExpression = "ControlNumber = :cn",
            ExpressionAttributeValues =
                new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> {{":cn", new AttributeValue { S = "123456789" } }}
        };

        var response = await client.QueryAsync(request);
```

I am returned the exact record I'm looking for with all the attributes.  The attributes in my DynamoDB table are all defined as strings.  I'm getting back data like this:

```
{
  "scannedCount": 5,
  "count": 2,
  "lastEvaluatedKey": null,
  "consumedCapacity": null,
  "items": [
    {
      "Status": {
        "nullvalue": null,
        "ss": null,
        "b": null,
        "bool": null,
        "ns": null,
        "l": null,
        "m": null,
        "n": null,
        "bs": null,
        "s": "READY"
      },
      "Type": {
        "nullvalue": null,
        "ss": null,
        "b": null,
        "bool": null,
        "ns": null,
        "l": null,
        "m": null,
        "n": null,
        "bs": null,
        "s": "OrderStatus"
      },  ......
```

It looks as if I get a value for every possible type of data that could be returned, in addition to my string, "s".   I think these are called data type descriptors, and they are all null, except for the string data type, which contains the data I actually want to see.  Why is this?  And how can I get back just the data, without all those null values that I don't care about.

For example, I expect to see:

```
{ "Status": "Ready", "Type":"OrderStatus"....}
```

UPDATE: I can run a similar query or even a get-item through the AWS CLI and get back the json as I expect.  So it appears the .NET SDK is adding the additional data type descriptors that I don't want to see.   Also, I am using Mulesoft 4 and it does the same thing as the .NET SDK.

Comment: I don't use the .Net SDK but does the Document Model help? See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DotNetSDKMidLevel.html#GetMidLevelDotNet

Answer (score 1):

This is the way it works if you are using the Document Model.

If you look at their example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryMidLevelDotNet.html) you'll see that they are printing all the values by calling "PrintDocument". Looking at this code, it is looping through and printing every attribute and the value.

```
    private static void PrintDocument(Document document)
    {
        //   count++;
        Console.WriteLine();
        foreach (var attribute in document.GetAttributeNames())
        {
            string stringValue = null;
            var value = document[attribute];
            if (value is Primitive)
                stringValue = value.AsPrimitive().Value.ToString();
            else if (value is PrimitiveList)
                stringValue = string.Join(",", (from primitive
                                in value.AsPrimitiveList().Entries
                                                select primitive.Value).ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", attribute, stringValue);
        }
    }
```

If you wish to continue down this road, you'll need to build your own mapping to deal with this. So, assuming we have an InventoryItem object that consists of a status and type (as strings for simplicity) you'd end up having a mapping function like this:

```
private InventoryItem Map(Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> result)
{
    return new InventoryItem
    {
        Id = Convert.ToInt32(result["Id"].N),
        Status = result["Status"].S,
        Type = result["Type"].S
    };
}
```

What it sounds like you want is to use the [Object Persistence Model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DotNetSDKHighLevel.html). With this, you'll be able to create classes that map to your DynamoDB table and you can easily execute queries resulting in objects.

So, with their example you'd create a model like this:

```
[DynamoDBTable("Inventory")]
  public class InventoryItem
  {
    [DynamoDBHashKey]   
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Status{ get; set; }
    public string Type{ get; set; }   
  }
```

And to get that item? Well, you simply have to do this:

```
 InventoryItem inventoryItem = context.Load<InventoryItem>("123456789");
```

I like this method more. You can't do as many operations with it, but it is much more like Django's ORM which I am used to.

Hope this helps!